# POST request for login page

Tags: url, post, ios6, authentication

I creating the app for my site and have a problem with signin. I have login page with login and pass fields and the "Login" button.

I tried to write post request (You can see it below) for sign in, but it doesn't work.

Please, give me some solutions.

I've been coding in Obj-C just a few weeks and I don't now many things.

```
NSString *login = loginField.text;
NSString *password = passField.text;



NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite",login, password]]; //Here you place your URL Link

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"connection successful");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLRequest HTTPMethod is by default "GET" and you need to set it to "POST" in your code.
My example shows a `NSMutableURLRequest` because I have had this code tested in an application. You should be able to do the same with `NSURLRequest` if you prefer that.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Hope this helps.